# run npm start as ENTRYPOINT from the Dockerfile

Tags: docker, npm-start

I am trying to build a dockerfile in which i am just starting a http-server.
My dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs && apt-get install -y npm
COPY testing /testing
RUN cd testing
RUN npm install

ENTRYPOINT npm start
```

Here testing is the project directory which consist of an `index.html` file and `package.json`.

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 5500"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.12.1"
  }
}
```

In my local machine the server is working properly. I think the `cd testing` command isn't appropriate and `npm install` is not taking the `package.json` file.

The docker image is formed under the Image ID - `6260786586cc`

and the error while running an image through command  is:

[image]

Comment: Replace `RUN cd testing` with `WORKDIR /testing`.

Comment: `docker build` and similar commands usually write out plain text; can you replace your image files with that plain-text output?  In general you should almost never paste screen shots of terminal windows into Stack Overflow posts, insert the actual text of what you're trying to show instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) instruction instead of `cd`.

```
WORKDIR testing
```

Each instruction in Dockerfile is executed in a separate container during build. So running `cd` to change directory during build doesn't work.